# How to add a new subdomain to kubernetes ManagedCertificate?

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using K8s ManagedCertificate to create a certificate on GCE. I wanted to add a new subdomain to my cert, so update the yaml file and did kubectl apply. I tried to describe my cert to see if everything is ok but found an error

```
Warning  BackendError  16m (x144 over 36h)  managed-certificate-controller  googleapi: Error 400: The ssl_certificate resource '< redated >' is already being used by '< redated >', resourceInUseByAnotherResource
```

Also in the describe I don't see the new sub domain I am trying to add as active.

```
Spec:
  Domains:
    web.sub1.domain1.com
    web.sub1.domain2.com
    web.newsub.domain2.com
    web.sub2.domain2.com
    web.sub1.domain3.com
Status:
  Certificate Name:    < redated >
  Certificate Status:  Active
  Domain Status:
    Domain:     web.sub1.domain1.com
    Status:     Active
    Domain:     web.sub1.domain2.com
    Status:     Active
    Domain:     web.sub2.domain2.com
    Status:     Active
    Domain:     web.sub1.domain3.com
    Status:     Active
  Expire Time:  2021-07-30T00:54:02.000-07:00
```

Comment: SSL certificates cannot be updated. They can only be replaced with a new certificate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As John Hanley mentioned you can't update SSL cert. [Google API for SSL cert doesn't have an update method](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/sslCertificates#methods). So deleted the resource using `kubectl delete -f <cert>.yaml` and created it again with `kubectl apply -f <cert>.yaml` and it worked